# I am trying to run a coredns server using quic, but facing an issue?

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, dns-server, quic

`I am trying to run a coredns server using quic, but getting empty response.

Here is the link to the github project of coredns: https://github.com/justus237/coredns

I have created a corefile for quic as follows:
`quic://.:1053 { tls cert/CA/example/example.crt cert/CA/example/example.decrypted.key whoami log hosts example.hosts }`

I have also created example.hosts file.
It works for all other protocols like DoT, DoH but not for QUIC.
[Coredns server running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzuwP.png)

I am trying to query the server using q client [q client](https://github.com/natesales/q)
but getting the below error:
[query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi03O.png)

here is my example.hosts file:
`127.0.0.1 localhost 192.168.0.1 www.example.com 192.168.0.2 www.instagram.com 192.168.0.3 www.wikipedia.com`

Comment: Is there a reason you using a fork of a fork of the [actual project](https://github.com/coredns/coredns) that hasn't been updated in years? Try an official version, if it still doesn't work the official bugtracker is probably more suitable.

Comment: Yes, they implemented an http3 server as a plugin in their coredns fork. So I need to use this fork.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to achieve? Blocking specific websites? Local mirror/cache?